# How to set HTTPBody?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

In Swift I'm trying to make a post request (using the `NSURLSession`) to sign in a user to a WebAPI web services.

The Url is `www.myurltest.com/Token` and I must pass the following string as POST body:

```
grant_type=password&username=MyUsername&password=MyPassword.
```

So in Swift I've make:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();

let url = NSURL(string:"www.myurltest.com/Token");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

Now I want to set the POST body (that is a string) but I don't know how:

```
request.HTTPBody = ?????
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you just need to turn the string into an NSData object. If your string is in a variable named `body`, your code will look like `request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`